# Countifs with Or condition across two columns

Tags: countif, sumproduct

I want to do something like a `COUNTIF` function that looks for matches across three columns; however, for the second and third columns, I want the formula to count only if the value is `'Yes'` in *one* of the columns (not both).

For example:

```
COUNTIF A2:A10 = "Yes" AND B2:B10 OR C2:C10 = "Yes"
```

I know `COUNTIFS` automatically apply the `AND` logic, and I seem to keep coming back to `SUMPRODUCT` in all my reading, but I don't know how to write the formula.

Comment: Since `COUNTIFS` only looks at the cells' *values*, for non-`AND` logic you have to provide it with a cell that has a different value based on that logic. I was able to get the functionality you want by creating a new column with the formula: `=XOR(IF(B2="Yes", TRUE, FALSE),IF(C2="Yes", TRUE, FALSE))`, then feeding those values into `COUNTIFS` with: `=COUNTIFS(A2:A10,"Yes",D2:D10,TRUE)`

Comment: This looks like excel to me. It would be beneficial if you could include that in the title and in the description. Specifying which version, in particular, you are using could be helpful as well.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about adding in another column so I'll do that. New to this forum so thanks for the tips.